# Dialogflow - 401 Error After Successful Account Linking/Login

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, http-status-code-401, google-home

Got Account Linking working with Dialogflow for the most part.
When the user is prompted to link accounts, they fill in the log in form, submit and should be redirected back to the Google Assistant. However, on a successful login, the user is redirected (with the following redirectURL):

https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/YOUR_PROJECT_ID#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=bearer&state=STATE_STRING

The redirect happens and I end up hitting the following error:

> 401. That's an error. Your client does not have permission to the
>        requested url /service/auth/handoffs/auth/complete. That's all we
>        know.

The weird part is. When the users tries to initiate a conversation with our agent again after hitting the 401 error, it will ask to link accounts again. The user presses Yes and then linking accounts is successful, without needing to enter in login credentials again.

My theory: the first time they try link accounts, they'll successfully authenticate but hit the error. The second time when they try again, since they are already authenticated (which I assume is saved in cache), it goes through.

Anyone know what could be causing the 401 event though they are logging in correctly?

Side note: Google documentation states: "If the user isn't signed in, complete your service's sign-in or sign-up flow.", so what I do is the users isnt logged in, I redirect to the login screen and pass through the State String that google passes through originally. When the user logs in, they are taken to the redirect url as mentioned above, with the state string still being the same. Not sure if this may be part of the cause.

Comment: Does this OAuth integration work normally, like through a web browser? Does the full requested URL include a protocol like `http://` or any other properties? Right now it seems like the URL is incomplete.